# How to create folder shortcut in ubuntu 18.4

Tags: directory, shortcuts

How to create folder shortcut in ubuntu 18.4

Do I need to install an app to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You can do it from the command line:

```
$ ln -s /my/folder /my/link
```

to enable creating links from file manager, open the preferences dialog,

[image: menu]

and under the "Behavior" tab, check the "Show action to create symbolic links" box

[image: Preferences Dialog]

Comment: Do I have to use the command line each time I want to create a folder shortcut?

Comment: I dont have a preferences section showing up anywhere when I go to documents. If I right click a folder or the header it does not show up

Comment: if there is a way to upload a screen shot I will do that as well to demonstrate. Thank you very much!

Comment: Got it - Thank you very much!
I just wasn't looking at it right.
that solved my problem - thank you kindly

Comment: It works for the desktop but not for the launcher dock. Is it possible to also put in on the launcher dock?

Comment: did you try making the link in file browser and then dragging it to your dock? if this answer worked, please hit the accept answer checkmark

Comment: Aaargh...why do they make such obvious functionality more difficult to access? I had to even go and activate single click.